# How to obtain the process id portably in C++?

Tags: c++, pid, portability

In standard C++, we can get an id for the current execution thread: [`std::this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id). But the language doesn't, at the time of writing, have an inherent notion of a process. I still want my process id, though.

So - what's the most portable, standards-friendly (albeit not language-standard) way to get the running process' ID in modern C++?

Notes:

- I realize some machines don't have processes, but then, they don't necessarily have threads either... so there's no reason why a cross-platform function with a fallback for degenerate cases should not exist.
- I'll want an actual process ID at least for POSIX-compliant OSes and Windows.

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have a concept of a process ID (or of a process, for that matter). Any means to obtain it are necessarily OS-specific. Imagine you somehow managed to obtain it - what would you do with it (in a portable C++ program)? What's the ultimate goal of the exercise?

Comment: Does "standards-friendly" mean *"today `boost`, possibly sometime in the future `std`"*?

Comment: What are you planning on using it for?

Comment: @Galik: Some inter-process communications.

Comment: @StoryTeller: That's a reasonable interpretation. But obviously it's a diffuse term.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That's not an issue: Fallback to some constant value, or throw an error, if we're not in a process with an id.

Comment: A machine may very well have threads but not processes (think single task controller).

Comment: @n.m.: Sure, but it might not even have threads. So if we can get non-existent thread IDs, we can get non-existent process IDs.

Comment: There ain't no inter-process communication in standard C++ either. Whichever library you are going to use for that, would probably also offer the way to obtain process ID, if it needs one.

Comment: A machine with no threads will likely have a partial C++ implementation with the threads library removed, so there's no thread concept available at all. There's no point in presenting a degenerate API that just returns errors.  Anyway, the concept of process ID is not needed for building an interprocess communication library.

Answer (score 9):

[Boost.Interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) has [boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::get_current_process_id](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/interprocess/detail/os_thread_functions.hpp).

The [ACE library](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html) provides various OS-related functions and has been ported to many platforms. See [here](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/versions.html) for a list. The library's [ACE_OS](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/6.4.7/html/libace-doc/a03715.html) namespace provides a [getpid](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/6.4.7/html/libace-doc/a03715.html#a2863eafa335d875e2e0a4f7abd21170e) implementation.

In general, there's no universal way to get the process ID on every platform since that aspect of the OS's process management is outside the scope of the C++ language.

Comment: Does ACE provide a sort of a C++ facade for most/all of POSIX?

Answer (score 7):

> Well, then, what's the most portable, standards-friendly way to get the running process' ID in (modern) C++?

As Igor's comment says, there's no standard C++ way, so the most portable, standards-friendly way is [`getpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpid.html).

You won't find anything else defined by a standard that can be used on a wider set of platforms.

Comment: 1. I didn't say standard... see question edit for emphasis of this point,. 2. Does `getpid()` work on Windows? I'm pretty sure there's some different voodoo there.

Comment: I know what you asked, you said "most portable, standards-friendly". That doesn't mean "portable to every OS" though, or even "portable to Windows". POSIX is widely portable, and a standard. If you really mean "portable to Windows and POSIX, and maybe other things" then you should have said that.

Comment: @einpoklum • to be standards-friendly and portable, you'll need a "firewall" API between your C++ code and whatever the OS provides as an API.  Write your C++ code to your edge firewall.  Implement the edge firewall on each platform as needed.

Comment: @Eljay: Indeed. I was just hoping such a wall (no need for the fire metaphor) already exists in common use.

Comment: @einpoklum • Looks like there are some off-the-shelve edge walls available.  But if none of them are suitable for your purposes, they're not very hard to create.  Yes, a bit of a bother to make the abstraction, but not hard.